# Creating a sliding row on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all here is my http://fiddle.jshell.net/clearblue/47r2Ltsk/2/

I'm trying to create an effect very similar to this one. Basically the only difference is that the second layer of columns should not resize like they do right now. I want to achieve an effect where the inner columns keep a fixed width.

For instance, as you can see, when the sliding happens the text is resizing and rewrapping a lot. It should stay fixed, and appear with the same width he has when the animation is complete.

The technique I used doesnt seem to allow that. I'm starting to wonder if it's even possible to do it with such few js.

Comment: So you want the columns to slide offscreen? How else could they stay the same width?

Comment: yes that's the wanted effect

Comment: You'll probably want to use a full-width column and not involve Bootstrap. Set up an absolutely-positioned element inside the column and simply manipulate its left position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using slickjs

here is the js part :

```
$('.top-slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  speed: 300,
  infinite: false,
  initialSlide: 3,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  variableWidth: true,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 991,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 767,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: I have to wait one day more

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/47r2Ltsk/3/).  You needed to make the third column `col-xs-12` to start.  Each column size is defined based on the element it is inside.  So to fill a `col-xs-3` parent, the element needs to be `col-xs-12`.  When it expands to a `col-xs-9` parent, you want it to be 1/3 of the total width, or `col-xs-4`.  So I added a toggle for that.